# C# assign textbox value to a variable in another class in another file

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, variables, methods

I have created a simple form **"people"** and there is another file **"Information.cs"**

In main for assign text box "txt_lname" value to a variable

```
String lastname = txt_lname.Text;
```

Then I want to use this value within  **"information class"** *(It is a thread class)*

How can I use it ?

(I have commented the place I wanted to use that value)

**Main Form**

```
namespace users
{
    public partial class people : Form
    {
        public people()
        {
            InitializeComponent();   
        }

        private void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String lastname = txt_lname.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

**Information Class**

```
namespace users
{ 
    class Information
    {             
        int[] idno = new int[10];
        int[] age = new int[10];
        string[] fname = new string[10];

        // Here I want to assign txt_lname.Text value to a variable
        lastname = txt_lname.Text; // This code is not working 

        public void run()
        {
            while (true)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < 600; i++)
                {
                    //Some code here

                    try
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*** Can I use value of a variable within run method in thread class ? if cannot then why ?**

Comment: Where is `txt_lname` declared? Read up on [scoping in c#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You have to create an instance of `Information` on your form and then pass the data to said instance. A classes' code won't magically be executed just because you added it to your project, you have to actually create an instance of the class.

So lets create and initialize an instance of `Information` on the form:

```
public partial class people : Form
{
    private Information _information;

    public people() {
        InitializeComponent();
        _information = new Information();
    }
}
```

You can now pass stuff to your instance of `Information`. But to do that you need a way to pass it, or in this case `Information` needs a way to receive a LastName. There's more than one way to do this but a common approach is to expose a `LastName` property on `Information`:

```
public class Information
{
    ...
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And now you can pass the value to the `LastName` property:

```
private void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    _information.LastName = txt_lname.Text;
}
```

Note: When you want to execute the run method on `Information` you'll do it through the instance just like when you're setting the LastName:

```
private void btn_run_click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    _information.run();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Make the Information class Static

```
public static class Information
```

And in your main form you can use it like

```
Information.LastName = txt_lname.Text;
```

But you also need to declare LastName as property. So add

```
public string LastName {get; set;}
```

into your Information Class.

Comment: Why does it needs to be static?

Comment: Seems weird to go with static.